# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have seen this error when I tried to change my password in my reactjs and nodejs project!

I tried to enter the old password wrong to check the error message, but it crashed the server. with this:

`Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Here is the code:

```
    router.put("/changepassword", validateToken, async (req, res) => {
  const { oldPassword, newPassword } = req.body;
  // console.log("change password", oldPassword);
  const user = await Users.findOne({ where: { fullName: req.user.fullName } });

  bcrypt.compare(oldPassword, user.password).then(async (match) => {
    if (!match) res.json({ error: "Wrong Password Entered!" });

    bcrypt.hash(newPassword, 10).then((hash) => {
      Users.update(
        { password: hash },
        { where: { fullName: req.user.fullName } }
      );
      res.json({ message: "SUCCESS" });
    });
    return;
  });
});
```

this is the client-code:

```
  const changePassword = () => {
    axios
      .put(
        `${targetServer}/auth/changepassword`,
        {
          oldPassword: oldPassword,
          newPassword: newPassword,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            accessToken: localStorage.getItem("accessToken"),
          },
        }
      )
      .then((res) => {
        // console.log("res.data", res.data);
        if (res.data.error) {
          toast.error("Something went wrong, please try again!", {
            className: "error-toast",
            draggable: true,
            position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
          });
          history.push("/");
          // console.log("res.data.error", res.data.error);
        }
      });
  };
```

Does any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `else` after `if`
because  the server send `res.json({ error: "Wrong Password Entered!" })`
and then it wants to send `res.json({ message: "SUCCESS" })`

```
router.put("/changepassword", validateToken, async (req, res) => {
  const { oldPassword, newPassword } = req.body;
  // console.log("change password", oldPassword);
  const user = await Users.findOne({ where: { fullName: req.user.fullName } });

  bcrypt.compare(oldPassword, user.password).then(async (match) => {
    if (!match) res.json({ error: "Wrong Password Entered!" });
    else {
    bcrypt.hash(newPassword, 10).then((hash) => {
      Users.update(
        { password: hash },
        { where: { fullName: req.user.fullName } }
      );
      res.json({ message: "SUCCESS" });
    });
   }
    return;
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey, it didn't give any error but wanted to display a message to the user that the entered password is wrong, also I will update my question add the client-code as well

Comment: when the clinet send wrong pass (!match) will be execute

Comment: Yeah, i know that, but i was wondering how to show the message in the client-side

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you code process something after sending the response to client.

Here in your case, what's happening is, that you haven't `return res.json()` in the first if statement due to which `bcrypt` start processing the after response had been sent.

or else add `if .. else`

Also user.Update being a promise you have to move res.json() in another then chain

like this

```
bcrypt.compare(oldPassword, user.password).then(async (match) => {
    if (!match) res.json({ error: "Wrong Password Entered!" });

    bcrypt.hash(newPassword, 10).then((hash) => {
      Users.update(
        { password: hash },
        { where: { fullName: req.user.fullName } }
      );
    }).then(() => res.json({ message: "SUCCESS" }) )
  });
```

Comment: Hey, I tried what you said but it didn't work, it gave the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Add the else code.

```
if (!match) res.json({ error: "Wrong Password Entered!" });
else // write code here
```

if not add else code.

When there is no match variable, the response occurs once and the next code is also executed, so it is an error that the response overlaps. To solve this, add an else statement.

is your code fix

```
  router.put("/changepassword", validateToken, async (req, res) => {
      const { oldPassword, newPassword } = req.body;
      // console.log("change password", oldPassword);
      const user = await Users.findOne({ where: { fullName: req.user.fullName } 
  });
  bcrypt.compare(oldPassword, user.password).then(async (match) => {
      if (!match) res.json({ error: "Wrong Password Entered!" });
      else {
          bcrypt.hash(newPassword, 10).then((hash) => {
          Users.update(
              { password: hash },
              { where: { fullName: req.user.fullName } }
          );
          res.json({ message: "SUCCESS" });
          });
      }
      return;
      });
  });
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your response, yeah it is what @muhammad maintained, it is working now I mean I doesn't crash the server, but I want to display a message to the user when they enter old password wrong! i just updated my question please take a look:)